# Redirect WooCommerce pages to My Account page if not logged in (Issue)

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

In WooCommerce I am redirecting non logged users to **My Account** page when they visit any WooCommerce page. But after user login (in My Account page) when I try to visit that same woocommerce page it's redirect me to **My Account** page. 
But when I visit any other WooCommerce pages its working perfect.

I am using this code for this purpose:

```
<?php
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        if(is_woocommerce() || is_shop() || is_cart() || is_checkout())  {
  
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id')) );
            exit();
        }
    }
?>
```

I think the problem is that it stores something in cache or another redirection issue, so when user visit same url it's redirected to **My Account** when is logged in.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You should try to embed your code in a custom function hooked in **`template_redirect`** action hook:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access');
function wc_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access() {

    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && ( is_woocommerce() || is_shop() || is_cart() || is_checkout() ) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id')) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on WooCommerce v2.6.x + v3.0.x and works

Comment: This code I have a already tested in my child theme but when I am login successfully in woo-commerce also I go to on  catalog page at that time it redirect on my account page(And it is occur some time not every time).

Comment: @Ket I have tested this code on both woocommerce versions, multiple times and I don't have this problem issue you got. So there is something particular in your theme or in some plugin, that is doing that issue…